# Numpy recarray functions throw TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, numpy, recarray

I would like to work with `numpy.recarrays` as described here: [numpy.recarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html)

I construct the `numpy.recarray` like described and want to execute simple `.max()`,`.sum()` methods:

```
a = np.recarray((2,), dtype=[('x', int), ('y', float), ('z', int)])
a.sum(axis=0)
```

However, I get:

> TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

What am I missing?

Comment: you can do `a.x.sum()`. That is `sum` on individual  fields, but not multiple fields.  `a` is not a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

From the final paragraph of [Structure Comparison](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#structure-comparison)

> [...] arithmetic and bitwise operations are not supported.

I suggest looking at Pandas for this sort of thing.